# Absolute Galois group acts transitively on roots of irreducible polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

During the solving of a homework problem I had encountered this question. Let $k$ be a base field and $k^{sep}$ its maximal separable extension. I know that the Galois group of $L/k$ - split field of separable irreducible polynomial acts transitively on roots, we can send one root to another and extend the map to $k$-automorphism of $L$, but I have no idea how to prove if it can be extended to $k$-automorphism of $k^{sep}$. And of course I don't know if there is some counterexample. Will be glad for some hints or help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\DeclareMathOperator{\ksep}{{k}^{\text{sep}}} \ksep \supseteq L \supseteq k$, and $L/k$ is Galois, then by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory we have
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\Gal}{Gal}
\Gal(L/k) \cong \frac{\Gal(\ksep/k)}{\Gal(\ksep/L)} \, .
$$
The quotient map $\Gal(\ksep/k) \to \frac{\Gal(\ksep/k)}{\Gal(\ksep/L)}$ is surjective, which shows that every element of $\Gal(L/k)$ is the restriction of an element of $\Gal(\ksep/k)$. What this extension looks like is not at all clear, as the proof of this fact uses Zorn's Lemma; see Proposition 7.4 (p. 91) of [Milne's Galois theory notes](https://jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf).

Comment: BTW, according to you, which note or book is easier/easiest to understand galois theory? Plz advise. For a beginner.

Comment: @Andrew I like Dummit and Foote's treatment. They set up the necessary background in chapter 13, and then cover Galois theory in chapter 14. This is all Galois theory of finite extensions, though; for infinite extensions, Milne's notes are the best resource I know of.